# Simple OOP Array argument not returning the value instead saying Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, oop

Simple OOP Array argument not returning the value instead saying  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  I don't know why it is not returning $this->data value which is an array

```
class MyClass{

    var $data;

    public function getData()
    {
        $data = array('Toyota'=>'Corolla','Honda' => 'Civic', 'Suzuki'=>'Mehran');
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function showData($comp)
    {

        foreach($this->data as $company => $model){

        if($company == $comp){
            return $comp.' is currently producing Model: '.$model;
             break;

            }
        }

    }

}
$cars = new MyClass();

echo $cars->showData('Honda');
```

Comment: Unless you call `getData()`, `$this->data` isn't set.

Comment: ^ hint: use a [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Comment: @NigelRen I know there are workarounds availble but my question is why it is not working it should return the value of $data so that I can use it in my other methods using $this->data

Comment: Saw your comment to the answer, looks like you're good now

Comment: @PatrickQ Got the point and surly I will use constructor when possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getData() function needs to be called so $data gets populated.

```
 $cars = new MyClass();
 $cars->getData();
 echo $cars->showData('Honda');
```

Comment: Ah yes I got it now simple but challenging. I'm new to the OOP not to the PHP so yeah that was really stupid question

Comment: Don't forget to follow @CD001 advice and learn about constructors and php classes in general. ( Derek Banas on YT has a quick video on it)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion yes I will follow his video